# How can I enforce a signature of a React component being passed in to another React component in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

This code I have is working quite well, the wrapping component naturally inherits all the properties of the component passed in, and is known to the editor when invoking the `WrappingComponent`. So, now it can take all the params and and splat them onto the invocation of whatever component is passed in.

But... how can I enforce that the component being passed in has a specific prop signature?

```
type EnforcedProps = {
  foo: boolean;
  bar: boolean;
 }

type WrappingComponentProps<T extends React.ComponentType<EnforcedProps>> = {
  wrappedComponent: T;
 } & React.ComponentProps<T>;
 
 const WrappingComponent = <T extends React.ComponentType<any>>({
  foo,
  bar,
  wrappedComponent: WrappedComponent,
  ...restProps
 }: WrappingComponentProps<T>): JSX.Element => {
    /**
     * Ultimately I'm going to do something special here with the
     * values foo & bar before rendering and control the wrapped 
     * component in a special way
     */
    return <WrappedComponent foo={foo} bar={bar} {...restProps}/>;
 };
 
 export default WrappingComponent;
```

Currently, if I try and change my WrappingComponent template signature to `const WrappingComponent = <T extends React.ComponentType<EnforcedProps>>` Typescript complains that:

`Type '{ foo: boolean; bar: boolean; } & Omit<WrappingComponentProps<T>, "foo" | "bar" | "wrappedComponent">' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<T, EnforcedProps>'.`

I half expected that if I used `EnforcedProps` instead of `any` to describe the props of the ComponentType that it would do some additional enforcement.

Still wrapping my head around some TypeScript stuff, specifically more advanced use cases of generics. Any help would be appreciated.